# Mongoose ODM: NumberInt is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB collection "test" contains a record:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f53cded3095c203024a884"), status : 0 }
```

I was connected to mongo by Node.js (Mongoose driver). Define schema for this collection:

```
"Test" : {
    status : { type : Number, default : 0 }
}
```

Field "status" is a binary flag, must be store only 0 or 1 number value. I wanna change this flag with update query:

```
test.update( { 'status' : 0 }, { $bit : { 'status' : { xor : NumberInt(1) } } }, function( err, result ) {
    if( err ) {
        console.log( 'err' );
    }
});
```

Mongoose was not found `NumberInt()` function:

```
ReferenceError: NumberInt is not defined
```

When i put simple number "1" without function `NumberInt()`, i not have any changes or errors.

In MongoDB shell thats query worked perfectly. How i can work with `NumberInt()` in Mongoose driver? Is it have another name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was some discussion about supporting `NumberInt` on [this feature request](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3102) in the Mongoose repository on GitHub. It was then added as a plugin through the `mongoose-int32` NPM package available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-int32). You can achieve the same behaviour as MongoDB's `NumberInt` by installing and then requiring the module using something like the following.

```
var NumberInt = require('mongoose-int32');
```

Comment: thanks. I declare var Int32 = require('mongoose-int32'); and execute query with this: test.update( { 'status' : 0 }, { $bit : { 'status' : { xor : new Int32(1) } } } ... );  but field 'status' is not changed again ( may be i'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried making the `type` of `status` an `Int32` instead of a `Number`?

Answer (score 0):

{ xor: 1-1 } quick hack worked for me.